# breaking a string equation into two parts in python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string such as 
`'(((a+b)+a)+c)'` which I'd like to break into two parts, the result would be `('((a+b)+a)','c')`.

If I were to run it again on the first element of the result it would give me `('(a+b)', 'a')`

and if I ran it again on `'(a+b)'` it would return `('a', 'b')`.

I was thinking I could do this via a regular expression but I couldn't figure this out and went down the path of having many if statements checking for opening and closing brackets but it gets a bit messy

Comment: not sure how this is too broad...

Comment: Spontaneously I'd say you need a parser.

Comment: @dimebucker91 what you really want to do is to solve the operation or simply split the string?

Comment: @AlbertoLópezPérez just split the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works on examples such as yours:

```
def breakit(s):
    count = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if count == 1 and c in '+-':
            return s[1:i].strip(), s[i+1:-1].strip()
        if c == '(': count +=1
        if c == ')': count -= 1
    return s

breakit(s)
>> ('((a+b)+a)', 'c')
breakit(_[0])
('(a+b)', 'a')
breakit(_[0])
('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

voila:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
def f(s):
    p=s.rsplit('+',1)
    return [p[0][1:],p[1][:-1]]

s='(((a+b)+a)+c)'

for i in range(3):
    k=f(s)
    s=k[0]
    print(k)
```

output:

```
['((a+b)+a)', 'c']
['(a+b)', 'a']
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: that doesn't work for all cases.. for example (((a+b)+c) + (a+b))

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd post my answer as well, not quite as elegant as the chosen solution but it works

```
def break_into_2(s):

    if len(s) == 1: 
        # limiting case
        return s

    # s[0] can either be a digit or '('
    if s[0].isdigit():
        # digit could be 10,100,1000,...
        idx = 0
        while s[idx].isdigit():
            idx += 1
        a = s[:idx]
        b = s[idx+1:]
        return a, b
    # otherwise, s[0] = '('
    idx = 1
    counter = 1
    # counter tracks opening and closing parenthesis
    # when counter = 0, the left side expression has
    # been found, return the idx at which this happens
    while counter:
        if s[idx] == '(':
            counter+=1
        elif s[idx] == ')':
            counter -=1
        idx +=1
    if s[:idx] == s:
        # this case occurs when brackets enclosing entire expression, s
        # runs the function again with the same expression from idxs 1:-1
        return break_into_2(s[1:-1])
    return s[:idx], s[idx+1:]
```